# How to append to a string on an ActiveRecord column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a concept of a Share which represents a specific stock owned by a particular shareholder. What I am trying to add now is functionality that supports tracking the "history" of this Share over time, given it can be transferred to other shareholders etc.

In my database, for each `Share` record there is currently a column `t.string "transaction_ids"`. I should probably change the column type I am assuming to something easier to work with. Open to suggestions here.

The two relevant methods are when creating new shares and then transferring ownership of the shares.

Here is how the Share is created initially.

```
@number_of_share_numbers_to_create.times do |i|
      Share.create(
        owner_id: params[:buying_shareholder_id], 
        captable_id: @transaction.captable.id, 
        company_id: @transaction.company.id, 
        share_number: @latest_share += 1,
        transaction_ids: @transaction.id #Save transaction id to DB
      )
end
```

Then when a `Share` is transferred, I have the following method.

```
@share_numbers_on_cap.each do |share|
      share.update_attribute(:owner_id, @buying_shareholder.id)
      # TODO Capture share history by pushing @transaction.id into the transaction_ids column. 
      # Perhaps I could do something like share.transaction_ids >> @transaction.id or something?
end
```

I know this current solution is not optimal, and I'd love some guidance on how to solve this in a more scalable way. Perhaps I should use a different column type and build an array? Would love some push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating another model to "log" the transactions that happened for a specific `Share` object.

For example:

```
class ShareTransfer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :share
  belongs_to :transaction
  # don't forget to enforce the presence of 
  # both foreign keys share_id and transaction_id

  # bonus: "freezing" the object after creation so you can never
  # update the logged object (= data integrity)
  before_save(on: :update) do
    errors.add(:base, :immutable, "Cannot update a frozen object")
  end
end
```

And change your current `Share#transaction_ids` to a simple `integer` column with a foreign key to the `transactions` table - an probably rename it as well - to end up with something like:

```
class Share < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :transaction # implies you have renamed the column transaction_ids to transaction_id (and changed the column type)
  has_many :share_transfers
end
```

Which enables you to do the following when a `Share` is transferred:

```
@share_numbers_on_cap.each do |share|
  # [your previous logic to change ownership]
  share.share_transfers.create!(transaction_id: share.transaction_id)
  # ^ to create history of the ownership change
end
```

This schema allows you to add extra fields to the `ShareTransfer` model, for example, the exact time when the transfer occurred (ex: `occurred_at`), the IP of both parties when the transfer was validated, etc. You can even `lock` the `ShareTransfer` table to be "insert only", preventing any user (or code) to update the data in there and ensuring the integrity of your logs.

Comment: Really like this solution, thanks so much! Gives lots of future flexibility.

Comment: @JP89 I don't know if you plan on having a lot more "logging" to do in your project, but you may want to go deeper with this configuration and make `ShareTransfer` a little bit more abstract (polymorphism), use a different DB schema (example: `logs` instead of `public`), use DB partitioning for perf optimization, etc.

Comment: BTW, as an experienced Web developer, I can tell you that storing several `id` in a column - could it be a string of `id`s joined with a coma or an array of integers - is not a clean solution: DBs have foreign keys since forever, use it :) It is preferable to have several tables rather than only one doing everything (for obvious performance reasons)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array column type (if you use postgres). But what I'd do is to move transaction ids to a separate DB table. It will let you easily add new ids and query them fast.

Comment: Hey! I am actually not using postgres, so should I use the column type json perhaps? 

`Transaction` is it's own model but what I'm thinking is that for each instance of `Share` I'd like to track which Transactions it has been associated with.

Comment: I'd create relation between those two models 1:n if you have one share per transaction (then keep share ids in transaction) or n:m if there could be many records on both sides (you need a linking model or `has_and_belongs_to_many` then).